# Mongodb driver which version work gridfs for php

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB GridFS via PHP. I am creating a connection following.

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
```

This code works in a simple insert. How I can use GridFS? The PHP driver needs to change or the existing PHP driver is fine.

I am using the following:

**PHP**  7.1.33 
**MongoDB version** v3.6.3 
MongoDB extension for PHP driver 
**MongoDB** extension version  1.6.1

Code for migration in MySQL to MongoDB

```
public function documentupload($offset = 0)
{
    // Export MySQL to MongoDB
    $this->autoRender = false;
    
    // MongoDB connection 
    $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
    $this->loadModel('Documentupload');
    
    // MySQL query to retrieve data       
    $documents = $this->Documentupload->find('all', array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'offset' => $offset,
    ));
    
    // Loop through export data in MongoDB
    foreach ($documents as $row) {
        echo (int)$row['Documentupload']['id'];
        echo "<br/>";
        $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

        $document1 = array(
            "id" => (int)$row['Documentupload']['id'],
            "documentfile" => new MongoDB\BSON\Binary($row['Documentupload']['documentfile'], 
                MongoDB\BSON\Binary::TYPE_GENERIC)
        );
        $bulk->insert($document1);
        $m->executeBulkWrite('agrilicense.documentupload', $bulk);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `GridFS`, you'll need to use `Bucket` class like this. Reference [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.8/reference/class/MongoDBGridFSBucket/)

```
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $bucket = new MongoDB\GridFS\Bucket($manager, 'databaseName');

    $source = '';   // resource Readable Stream
    $metadata = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $result = $bucket->uploadFromStream('example.txt', $source, [
        'metadata' => $metadata
    ]);
    print_r($result);   // Outputs MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

This will create an fs.files document the following abridged data:

```
{
    filename: "example.txt"
    metadata: { foo: "bar" }
    // other fields follow...
}
```

I've tried this locally and it's working code

**MongoDB Community Server** - **3.6**

**mongodb/mongodb php library** - **1.6.1**

**MongoDB Driver version (pecl)** - **1.6.1**

**MongoDB PHP Extension Module**

```
/etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d/50-mongodb.ini
mongodb
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.6.1
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libmongoc bundled version => 1.15.2
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Comment: Sorry Haridarshan code is not work and show error "Class 'MongoDB\GridFS\Bucket' not found"

Comment: Official document [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.8/tutorial/gridfs/) says `You can construct a GridFS bucket using the PHP extension’s MongoDB\Driver\Manager class`. Check `mongodb/mongodb` library version

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found any solution. I want to share. All PHP extension version is okay.
Go to github mongodb library here all documentations are available.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Create a blank folder and run

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

If Composer not install first install composer. then put vendor folder in your project. after that **include autoload.php** file in your file. After included this file mongodb office site tutorial work fine.

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.8/tutorial/

I am working in cakephp so my code like.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'mongo_driver', array('file' => 'mongo_driver'.DS.'autoload.php'));
    

$bucket = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->selectGridFSBucket();

$stream = $bucket->openUploadStream('cib_rc.pdf');

$contents = file_get_contents('/home/shiva/Documents/CIB & RC.pdf');
fwrite($stream, $contents);
fclose($stream);
```

Here **test** is my database name. **fs.chunks** and **fs.file** automatic crated through mongodb.